# What is the intuition behind the Iterator.get_next method?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

The name of the method [`get_next()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/data/Iterator#get_next) is a little bit misleading. The documentation says

> Returns a nested structure of `tf.Tensor`s representing the next element.
>
> In graph mode, you should typically call this method **once** and use its result as the input to another computation. A typical loop will then call `tf.Session.run` on the result of that computation. The loop will terminate when the `Iterator.get_next()` operation raises `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError`. The following skeleton shows how to use this method when building a training loop:

```
dataset = ...  # A `tf.data.Dataset` object.
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

# Build a TensorFlow graph that does something with each element.
loss = model_function(next_element)
optimizer = ...  # A `tf.compat.v1.train.Optimizer` object.
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  try:
    while True:
      sess.run(train_op)
  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    pass
```

Python also has a function called [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), which needs to be called every time we need the next element of the iterator. However, according to the documentation of `get_next()` quoted above, `get_next()` should be called only once and its result should be evaluated by calling the method `run` of the session, so this is a little bit unintuitive, because I was used to the Python's built-in function `next`. In [this script](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/bayesian_neural_network.py), `get_next()` is also called only and the result of the call is evaluated at every step of the computation.

What is the intuition behind `get_next()` and how is it different from `next()`? I think that the next element of the dataset (or feedable iterator), in the second example I linked above, is retrieved every time the result of the first call to `get_next()` is evaluated by calling the method `run`, but this is a little unintuitive. I don't get why we do not need to call `get_next` at every step of the computation (to get the next element of the feedable iterator), even after reading the note in the documentation

> NOTE: It is legitimate to call `Iterator.get_next()` multiple times, e.g. when you are distributing different elements to multiple devices in a single step. However, a common pitfall arises when users call `Iterator.get_next()` in each iteration of their training loop. `Iterator.get_next()` adds ops to the graph, and executing each op allocates resources (including threads); as a consequence, invoking it in every iteration of a training loop causes slowdown and eventual resource exhaustion. To guard against this outcome, we log a warning when the number of uses crosses a fixed threshold of suspiciousness.

In general, it is not clear how the Iterator works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that `get_next` adds some operations to the graph such that, every time you evaluate them, you get the next element in the dataset. On each iteration, you just need to run the operations that `get_next` made, you do not need to create them over and over again.

Maybe a good way to get an intuition is to try to write an iterator yourself. Consider something like the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()

# Make an iterator, returns next element and initializer
def iterator_next(data):
    data = tf.convert_to_tensor(data)
    i = tf.Variable(0)
    # Check we are not out of bounds
    with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assert_less(i, tf.shape(data)[0])]):
        # Get next value
        next_val_1 = data[i]
    # Update index after the value is read
    with tf.control_dependencies([next_val_1]):
        i_updated = tf.compat.v1.assign_add(i, 1)
        with tf.control_dependencies([i_updated]):
            next_val_2 = tf.identity(next_val_1)
    return next_val_2, i.initializer

# Test
with tf.compat.v1.Graph().as_default(), tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    # Example data
    data = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4])
    # Make operations that give you the next element
    next_val, iter_init = iterator_next(data)
    # Initialize iterator
    sess.run(iter_init)
    # Iterate until exception is raised
    while True:
        try:
            print(sess.run(next_val))
        # assert throws InvalidArgumentError
        except tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError: break
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Here, `iterator_next` gives you something comparable to what `get_next` in an iterator would give you, plus an initializer operation. Every time you run `next_val` you get a new element from `data`, you don't need to call the function every time (which is how `next` works in Python), you call it once and then evaluate the result multiple times.

EDIT: The function `iterator_next` above could also be simplified to the following:

```
def iterator_next(data):
    data = tf.convert_to_tensor(data)
    # Start from -1
    i = tf.Variable(-1)
    # First increment i
    i_updated = tf.compat.v1.assign_add(i, 1)
    with tf.control_dependencies([i_updated]):
        # Check i is not out of bounds
        with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assert_less(i, tf.shape(data)[0])]):
            # Get next value
            next_val = data[i]
    return next_val, i.initializer
```

Or even simpler:

```
def iterator_next(data):
    data = tf.convert_to_tensor(data)
    i = tf.Variable(-1)
    i_updated = tf.compat.v1.assign_add(i, 1)
    # Using i_updated directly as a value is equivalent to using i with
    # a control dependency to i_updated
    with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assert_less(i_updated, tf.shape(data)[0])]):
        next_val = data[i_updated]
    return next_val, i.initializer
```

Comment: In your example, you're doing `next_val = data[i]`, but isn't `i` a variable always equal to zero?

Comment: @nbro `i` is zero initially, but then I use `assign_add` to increment it, _after_ `data[i]` has been retrieved, and then I use `identity` _after_ `i` has been incremented, so whenever you get `next_val`, `i` is automatically incremented afterwards. So `i` really holds a count of the number of times `next_val` has been evaluated. Note I'm not saying this is how iterators are actually implemented in TF (I think they use some queues system), but from the point of view of usage it is analogous.

Comment: Which `next_val` are you returning from the function `iterator_next`? It is also not clear why you use `tf.identity` here. I understand that `sess.run(iter_init)` will initialize the variable `i = tf.Variable(0)`, so `i` will take the value of zero after `sess.run(iter_init)` is executed. In general, it is not clear to me how the call `sess.run(next_val)` triggers the execution of `tf.compat.v1.assign_add(i, 1)` and the related code.

Comment: @nbro I refactored a bit for clarity. It is important to note how [`tf.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) is used. `next_val_1 = data[i]` is only executed after `tf.assert_less` is (so it is always valid). `assign_add` is only executed after `next_val_1` (so `next_val_1` has the value _before_ `i` is updated). `tf.identity` does nothing, but thanks to the control dependencies it makes `next_val_2` such that has the same value as `next_val_1` but its evaluation triggers the variable update `i_updated`.

Comment: @nbro So evaluating `next_val_2` requires evaluating first `i_updated`, which requires first `next_val_1` (from where `next_val_2 gets its value), which requires first asserting that `i` has a valid value.

Comment: Now it is clearer, but not everything. `next_val_1` is never returned from `iterator_next`. When you call `print(sess.run(next_val))`, the evaluation of `next_val` should be printed to the output, which should correspond to the value of `next_val_2` returned from the `iterator_next` function. When you call `sess.run(next_val)`, which part of the code of `iterator_next` is executed and why? For example, `i = tf.Variable(0)` cannot be executed every time you call `sess.run(next_val)` because, in that case, `i` would always be zero.

Comment: @nbro `next_val`, in the `# Test` block corresponds to `next_val_2` from `iterator_next`. The value of `next_val_2` is the same as `next_val_1`, but the difference is that `next_val_2` has additional control dependencies (`tf.identity` is a do-nothing op that is necessary to attach the control dependencies to it). When `next_val_2` is evaluated, `i_updated` is evaluated before. At the same time, `i_updated` cannot be evaluated until `next_val_1` has been evaluated. So in total, every time you run `next_val_2` you run: 1. `assert_less` 2. `next_val_1` 3. `i_updated` 4. `next_val_2`.

Comment: Right, `next_val_2` is equal to `next_val_1`. I had missed the statement `next_val_2 = tf.identity(next_val_1)`. All those control dependencies are only used to increment the index to get the next element.

Comment: @nbro Yes, that's right. I have added a simpler version of `iterator_next` that may make it easier to understand, starting `i` in `-1` and incrementing it _before_ doing `data[i]`, so you do not need to have the additional `tf.identity` later.

Comment: To conclude, when we call `sess.run(next_val)`, we are just evaluating the part of the graph necessary to return the evaluated `next_val`, so, for example, `i = tf.Variable(-1)` is not evaluated every time we call `sess.run(next_val)`, but only the parts of the code in the function `iterator_next` that are necessary to get the evaluated `next_val`.

Comment: @nbro Yes, every time you evaluate something in a graph, it will evaluate first all the operations it depends on (and nothing else). For example, in `c = a + b`, evaluating `c` requires evaluating `a` and `b` first. Using control dependencies you can add additional "artificial" dependencies to ensure that when you evaluate some operation something else is evaluated too. The initialization of `i` to `-1` is executed only once at the beginning (`sess.run(iter_init)`), because `next_val` does not depend on it.